# Count Words in Trie

Tags: java, trie

```
 int count=0;
     public  int countwords(TrieNode root){

        if (root.isTerminating==true)
            count++;

        for (int i=0;i<26;i++){
            if (root.children[i]!=null)
        countwords(root.children[i]);
        }

        return count;
    }
```

this function is used to count number of words in a trie it gives me wrong answer whats wrong here?i have used isTerminating to distinguish a word from another.

Comment: What wrong answer do you get? What answer did you expect? How do you know the trie is not corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

```
public int countwords(TrieNode root) {
   // variable localized because it is a recursive call
   // also because we add to this variable in the loop
   int count = 0;

   // if condition simplified
   if (root.isTerminating)
       count++;

   for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
       if (root.children[i] != null)
           // you need to save the result of the recursive call
           count += countwords(root.children[i]);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Your approach is fine but what's wrong if we take count as global

Comment: What is your sample input and output of your code? Is it different than mine?

Comment: mine gives wrong output but yours give correct output.

Comment: If you can give me your sample reproducible input, I could explain exactly why yours doesn't work

Comment: Also, If it works for you, upvote and accept the answer by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer for future readers.